# Can I use web3 with flask framework?

Tags: web3js

I want to know if it is possible to use the web3 API with the flask framework instead of meteor or nodejs. if so how do I add it to my flask project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are referring to writing python code to interact with Ethereum. If you want to integrate Ethereum with your python code, then you could go for the [web3py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py) package. It allows you to write interactions with the blockchain or specific smart contracts (assuming you have the ABI). It is basically a python implementation for web3.js.

Documentation for web3py can be found here: [web3py docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Documentation for web3.js can be found here: [web3.js docs](http://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)